how to make the systemctl status output auto wrap
I am using this command to show status info:
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ system]# systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-10-11 20:24:39 CST; 1min 52s ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 3076745 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 12 (limit: 22976)
   Memory: 95.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─3076745 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet>

Oct 11 20:24:40 iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ kubelet[3076745]: I1011 20:24:40.713781 3076745 reconciler_common.go:258] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume sta>
Oct 11 20:24:40 iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ kubelet[3076745]: I1011 20:24:40.713816 3076745 reconciler_common.go:258] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume sta>

the output log only contains part of content, how to output the whole line and auto wrap the line content if it exceed the screen? I have tried no pager like this:
[root@iZm5e2jhfbrshckqh6qdbuZ system]# systemctl --no-pager status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-10-11 20:24:39 CST; 6min ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 3076745 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 12 (limit: 22976)
   Memory: 135.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─3076745 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet…

this just replace the > to .... and still could not show the whole content. Am I missing something?

With --no-pager, systemctl status should show you a hint:
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

Running
systemctl status --no-pager -l kubelet

should show you everything.
